# The priority of the adverb "at first" and the modal "should"

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verbs, adverbs

Which one is the correct usage ?

`We at first should examine all documents`

`We should at first examine all documents`

I think the second one sounds more correct.

Comment: The *at* seems incongruous there. If you're just describing the order of things that need doing, you don't want the *at*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the second one seems more correct.
But the first one can be made correct too:

> We, at first, should examine all documents.

I think there is another possibility in which the sentence can be written.

> We should examine all documents at first.

Comment: Or, “At first we should examine all documents.”